# Would it be possible to download Kali Linux with the latest packages already installed?

Tags: usb, kali-linux, liveusb

Would it be possible to download Kali Linux with the latest packages already installed? I got this pendrive that I want to use with encrypted persistence, but installing the packages with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` takes forever. I would like to flash the USB again with a full version of Kali, all packages included.

Comment: Just download 2019.3 which was released on 2nd September. Then keep an eye on https://distrowatch.com/?newsid=10658 for updated releases.

Comment: I got that one, but it doesn't come with everything pre installed

Comment: What other packages do you download? The above comment would get you around having to wait so long for `update` & `upgrade`